# How can I make my CSS sprites responsive for different screen sizes?

Tags: css, image, media-queries, sprite, responsive

I made some CSS sprites for my website recently as I wanted my image to change on hover. I had a issue with them but had some help and now they work great. The relevant post is here: [Issue with CSS sprite when hovering over an image with a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60106051/issue-with-css-sprite-when-hovering-over-an-image-with-a-link)

Unfortunately these CSS sprites aren't responsive and stay the same size. Normal images on my website get smaller just fine on other screen sizes.

I'm trying to do a media query in CSS to change the size, but I've not had much luck. I'd super appreciate any help.

The CSS and HTML I'm using for my image sprites is this:

```
#home a img {
  display: none;
}
#home a  {
  background:url("https://via.placeholder.com/420x210");
  position: absolute;
  width: 210px;
  height: 210px;
  display: block;
}
#home:hover a  {
  background-position: -210px 0;
}

<div id="home">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/210x210?text=original%20image">
  <a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please provide the `html` too ?

Comment: Use background-size